# Is there any way to integrate Unity 5.4 with IOS swift using xcode 8?

Tags: unity-game-engine, swift3, xcode8

I have tried integrating Unity 5.4 with native swift using xcode 7 and was successful, however with the upgrade in xcode to 8.  I have not been able to use the same build to compile.

Comment: How did you do that with xcode 7? And what does the error message say in Xcode 8?

Comment: maybe this forum announcement helps: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-10-0-and-xcode-8-compatibility.430103/